# Optimize XSLT code by eliminating repeating code

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

This XSLT transformation works, but I am repeating the same code multiple times, which makes it very redundant!

How can I optimize this?

```
<xsl:for-each select="RVWT">
    <xsl:variable name="rvwt" select="tokenize(., '\|')"/>
    <TextTypeCode>08</TextTypeCode>
    <Text textformat="05">
        <xsl:value-of select="$rvwt[1]"/>
    </Text>
    <TextSourceTitle>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring($rvwt[2], 3))"/>
    </TextSourceTitle>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:if test="not(RVWT)">
    <xsl:for-each select="RVW">
        <xsl:variable name="rvwt" select="tokenize(., '\|')"/>
        <TextTypeCode>08</TextTypeCode>
        <Text textformat="05">
            <xsl:value-of select="$rvwt[1]"/>
        </Text>
        <TextSourceTitle>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring($rvwt[2], 3))"/>
        </TextSourceTitle>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I want to optimize my xslt! it works, but is bloated.

Comment: It is best to organize repeatedly used code within an `<xsl:function>` -- this is one of the best features of XSLT 2.0. Have you tried this idea? More details below.

Answer (score 4):

**I. I would use the best that XSLT 2.0 can offer: creating a function**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 
  <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:sequence select=
      "my:Extract(RVW[not(../RVWT)] | RVWT)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="my:Extract">
    <xsl:param name="pItems" as="item()+"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$pItems">
        <xsl:variable name="vItemTokens" select="tokenize(., '\|')"/>
        <TextTypeCode>08</TextTypeCode>
        <Text textformat="05">
            <xsl:value-of select="$vItemTokens[1]"/>
        </Text>
        <TextSourceTitle>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring($vItemTokens[2], 3))"/>
        </TextSourceTitle>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
    <RVWT>a|bbbTail|c</RVWT>
    <RVWT>d|eeeTail|f</RVWT>
    <RVWT>g|hhhTail|i</RVWT>
    
    <RVW>p|qqqTail|r</RVW>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<TextTypeCode>08</TextTypeCode>
<Text textformat="05">a</Text>
<TextSourceTitle>bTail</TextSourceTitle>
<TextTypeCode>08</TextTypeCode>
<Text textformat="05">d</Text>
<TextSourceTitle>eTail</TextSourceTitle>
<TextTypeCode>08</TextTypeCode>
<Text textformat="05">g</Text>
<TextSourceTitle>hTail</TextSourceTitle>
```

**when applied on this document**:

```
<t>
    <RVWTX>a|bbbTail|c</RVWTX>
    <RVWTX>d|eeeTail|f</RVWTX>
    <RVWTX>g|hhhTail|i</RVWTX>
    
    <RVW>p|qqqTail|r</RVW>
</t>
```

**again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<TextTypeCode>08</TextTypeCode>
<Text textformat="05">p</Text>
<TextSourceTitle>qTail</TextSourceTitle>
```

---

**II. Do note**:

With this approach we have the added benefit that the function accepts any sequence of items, not only elements.

**For example, one could call the function like this**:

```
my:Extract(('a|bbbTail|c', 'd|eeeTail|f'))
```

**and still get the wanted result**:

```
<TextTypeCode>08</TextTypeCode>
<Text textformat="05">a</Text>
<TextSourceTitle>bTail</TextSourceTitle>
<TextTypeCode>08</TextTypeCode>
<Text textformat="05">d</Text>
<TextSourceTitle>eTail</TextSourceTitle>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a template

```
<xsl:template match="RVWT | RVW">
    <xsl:variable name="rvwt" select="tokenize(., '\|')"/>
    <TextTypeCode>08</TextTypeCode>
    <Text textformat="05">
        <xsl:value-of select="$rvwt[1]"/>
    </Text>
    <TextSourceTitle>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring($rvwt[2], 3))"/>
    </TextSourceTitle>
</xsl:template>
```

and then in the parent you process `<xsl:apply-templates select="if (RVWT) then RVWT else RVW"/>`.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you could do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="RVWT | RVW[not(../RVWT)]">
    <xsl:variable name="rvwt" select="tokenize(., '\|')"/>
    <TextTypeCode>08</TextTypeCode>
    <Text textformat="05">
        <xsl:value-of select="$rvwt[1]"/>
    </Text>
    <TextSourceTitle>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring($rvwt[2], 3))"/>
    </TextSourceTitle>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Alternatively, `<xsl:for-each select="if (RVWT) then RVWT else RVT">...</xsl:for-each>`